# Objective-C intermediate object optimization

Tags: objective-c

I usually do option B as it allows me to do some debugging on the dictionary if I need to (as shown in option C). It also looks cleaner in my opinion. 
This might probably be a non-issue but I'm wondering if options B or C use more memory or if there is even something else to consider when doing this in iOS programming. By the way, I'm using ARC.

**Is there an advantage on using option A as opposed to option B or C?**

```
// OPTION A
NSString *someString = [[self grabDictionaryFromDB] objectForKey:@"someField"];

// OPTION B
NSDictionary *dbRow = [self grabDictionaryFromDB]; // dbRow ONLY gets used in the next line
NSString *someString = [dbRow objectForKey:@"someField"];

// OPTION C
NSDictionary *dbRow = [self grabDictionaryFromDB]; // dbRow ONLY gets used in the next two lines
NSLog(@"Row: %@", dbRow);
NSString *someString = [dbRow objectForKey:@"someField"];
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062162/does-an-auxiliary-variable-with-a-pointer-have-any-performance-memory-impact).

Comment: have you done any speed test? I guess, the numbers can tell you the answer...

Comment: @Adam thanks, that explains it nicely. I accepted dasblinken's answers since he took the time to write it down (and I saw it before your comment!). holex, speed test yielded no significant results, I was more concerned with memory though (and I have no idea how to test memory usage in this situation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that options A and B will be optimized into exactly the same output by the compiler, so the only thing that you gain with option B is readability. Option C will likely require an extra store instruction and a pair of `[retain]` / `[release]` from the ARC, but you would not notice the impact compared to options A or B.

Comment: I haven't tested it but there should be no retains and no releases from arc. Also, **if you compile with optimizations**, there likely is no extra store instruction or extra usage of space. There may be an extra register-to-register move instruction for option C. If the surrounding code is complex and uses a lot of variables, there may be an extra load instruction for option C (load, not store). If you compile without optimizations (debug mode) then it's a completely different story.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Option B because it is much more easily modified in the future.  Let me present two scenarios:

Issue One:  You want to perform another operation using that dictionary.

```
//Option A version
NSString *someString = [[self grabDictionaryFromDB] objectForKey:@"someField"];
NSString *someOtherString = [[self grabDictionaryFromDB] objectForKey:@"someOtherField"];

//Option B version
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [self grabDictionaryFromDB];
NSString *someString = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"someField"];
NSString *someOtherString = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"someOtherField"];
```

What if [self grabDictionaryFromDB] takes a long time to execute?  Suddenly you are executing it twice instead of once, where as you could just be saving the returned dictionary pointer and only execute it once.

Issue Two: What if you suddenly want to access a different dictionary in the future?  With the above options, you would only have to change one line of code in Option B, no matter how many times you were accessing the dictionary. In Option B, you just have to change the value of myDictionary.  In Option A, you would have to change a bunch of lines of code.